# Why is this route in Rails 3 with a custom action not working? (better way?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following code in my routes.rb:

```
match 'users/linkedin' => "users#linkedin", :as => :register_linkedin
```

My expectation is that when I have a redirect_to register_linkedin_url, I will be redirected to domain.com/users/linkedin.

That should then result in Controller Users with action linkedin being executed.

This is what I get in the logs:

> Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/users/linkedin
>   Completed 302 Found in 28333ms
>
> Started GET "/users/linkedin" for
>   127.0.0.1 at Thu Apr 14 01:12:01 -0700 2011   Processing by
>   UsersController#show as HTML
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"linkedin"}
>   Completed   in 94ms

This is what I get in 'rake routes':

> register_linkedin
>   /users/linkedin(.:format)
>   {:action=>"linkedin",
>   :controller=>"users"}

So the routes aren't working properly.  How do I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're probably using `resources :users` in your routes

if you want to keep your `show` action, and use the linkedin part too, put your custom route before the `resources :users`

doing that, routing will match `linkedin` if the request is specific (users/linkedin) and if not, will continue searching and the next one will be `show` of course

read more about routing in general [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: hi, so what should I do?  I still use the "show" users -- this is just a custom version of creating a new user that doesn't work with devise

Comment: okay this is wht it was --- but am realizing that I should somehow just find a way to use the "new" action if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are matched in the order they are defined. Put more specific routes higher than less-specific ones.

In your case, just make sure you define your custom route for `users/linkedin` before your more generic `resources :users` route is defined.